# Accessing HttpServletRequest during DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticate in Spring Security

Tags: spring, authentication, servlets, spring-security

I need to access the `HttpServletRequest` object from within my `DaoAuthenticationProvider` in Spring security.

The security component extends the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` and we override the `authenticate` method to perform some custom authentication / validation. The additional check is required to validate user's ip-address which comes in the request url as a query string parameter (Ex: `http://domain.com/context?ip=192.168.0.1`).

The current approach I am trying is to make use of `RequestContextHolder` thread-local and get the http request in my custom `DAOAuthenticationProvider`.

Some other solutions that I read here and on spring forums seems to suggest to inject `AuthenticationDetailsSource`, use of `custom-filter` and other steps which I don't understand due to being new to spring security.

We would have different web applications which use the same security component to perform authentication.

Can someone please point me in a correct direction or help me with any approaches implemented previously ?

Comment: Which version of Spring Security are you using?

Comment: Spring Security 3.0.4.  If i use RequestContextHolder during authenticate will it have the same http request as obtained in Spring Security or can it lead to funny results where-in my RequestContextHolder has a different instance of the http request and the one being used in Authentication token is different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Spring's [RequestContextFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/RequestContextFilter.html) in your web.xml. This way, attributes will be saved on current thread on every request. Then, you can get original HtttpServletRequest:

```
ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
HttpServletRequest request = attributes.getRequest();
```

Comment: @LukeTaylor: Sorry, what is OP?

Comment: @sinuhepop : Just to let you know that what you suggested also works :). I just wanted a way to get that done using Spring security and not introduce any additional filters ! :)

Comment: @AnkurSaxena: I prefer Luke Taylor solution, too. But I understood (wrongly) that you didn't want to use this kinds of solutions.

Comment: @sinuhepop - I just came back to revisit the solution. While what LukeTaylor suggested worked well when using basic authentication in a web application, things start to get messed up when trying to acheive a similar goal in Spring-WS. So I went ahead and implemented your solution, which looks to be working the exact same way and serving my purpose, also is much simpler :). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `RequestContextHolder` and it effectively contains the same request, though Spring Security will usually wrap the incoming request, so you may get a different reference depending on whether you place the `RequestContextFilter` before or after the Spring Security chain (note that you could easily check this yourself by comparing the value returned from `RequestContextHolder` with the request in an application controller).

It is also relatively easy to inject a custom `AuthenticationDetails` as you mentioned:

```
package com.mycompany;

public class MyWebAuthenticationDetailsSource implements AuthenticationDetailsSource {
    public Object buildDetails(Object context) {
        return ((HttpServletRequest)context).getParameter("ip");
    }
}
```

Then use

```
<bean id="ads" class="com.mycompany.MyWebAuthenticationDetailsSource />

<bean id="formLoginFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationDetailsSource" ref="ads" />
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationmanager" />
</bean>
```

and add this as a custom filter as described in the reference manual. In 3.1 the namespace [supports this directly in the `form-login` element](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-form-login). `Authentication.getDetails()` will then return the value of your "ip" parameter.

Note that you probably shouldn't be using 3.0.4, as it has known security vulnerabilities.

Also, can you explain how the "ip" parameter is being set?

Comment: Thanks for your help on this Luke, the proxy layer rewrites the incomming url to include the client's ip address as part of the url, so we can extract it from the http request parameters. I will try to get ahead with this and let you know on my progress !

Comment: I implemented your solution and it works great. I observed some minor hiccups when using Basic authentication the UsernamePasswordAuthentication filter is not invoked. Instead I used BasicAuthenticationFilter. It is positioned '_before_' the BASIC_AUTH_FILTER. I am just amazed by the capabilities of Spring security framework and look forward to exploring it even further! Thanks for your help with this.